# Sending variable from volt to custom function

Tags: twig, phalcon, volt

I have created a custom function I can access from the volt. The function seems to work fine, but I cannot manage to send the variable to the function. It sends the variable as text instead of its value.

The twig function:

```
$volt->getCompiler()->addFunction('getusergroup', function ($user) {
    return \Models\User::getUserGroup($user);
});
```

The function in the Model:

```
public static function getUserGroup($user) {
    return UserGroup::find(array('conditions' => 'user_id = ' . $user));
}
```

The lines in Twig to call the function:

```
{% for member in getusergroup(staff.id) %}
    {{ member.Group.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

The error I get:

> 'Scanning error before 'staff->id' when parsing: SELECT
>   [Models\UserGroup].* FROM [Models\UserGroup] WHERE user_id =
>   $staff->id (78)' (length=131)

As you can see, in stead of `$staff->id` being an integer, it's the text.

How do I go about sending the actual ID to the function?

By the way, I am using twig in combination with Phalcon and followed the instructions in this article: http://phalcontip.com/discussion/60/extending-volt-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dump `$user` inside of your method `public static function getUserGroup($user)`, you will receive this *$staff->id*, but you actually want something like *42*.

To avoid this register the Volt function like this:

```
$volt->getCompiler()->addFunction('getusergroup', function ($resolvedArgs, $exprArgs) {
    return 'Models\User::getUserGroup(' . $resolvedArgs . ')';
});
```

More info on [Extending Volt Functions](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#id1)

Comment: I would have never guessed that logic, putting all within quotes. But it worked like a charm. Thanx Nikolay

Comment: That's why we have documentation :)

Comment: Did not find that page using Google, that's why the many thanx ;)