# Phalcon PhP currency volt filter

Tags: php, phalcon

I've been reading [Phalcon template engine](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html) documentation and so far I couldn't find a filter for currency. Do it exist in volt engine? If not, how can I create one?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's in docs how to add filters - https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#id2

Comment: @Juri do you know where exactly I create the class and how to include it?

Comment: Yesterday another user had similar question, it was about volt functions, but filters are almost identical syntax. However you have to write the custom logic for currency conversions. The topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148199/phalcon-volt-array-is-of-string-type

Comment: You don't have to add class, just in service definition you have to add new filter to compiler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phalcon PhP - Unkown filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175399/phalcon-php-unkown-filter)