# Phalcon PhP - Unknown filter

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying to create custom filter for currency so I can use in my .volt templates. This is how I register the filter in my services.php

```
$di->setShared('filter', function() {
    $filter = new \Phalcon\Filter();
    $filter->add('currency', function ($value) {
        if($value === '') {
            return NULL;
        } else {
            return $value; // @todo implement the currency formatting
        }
    });
    return $filter;
});
```

Then when I try to use it in my .volt template, like this `{{ quote['total_fees']|currency }}` I get the following message `Unknown filter "currency"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i already posted link, but okay, here you go again - https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/volt.html#id2. It should look like this:

```
$di->set('view', function() {
    $view = new View();
    $view->registerEngines([
        '.volt' => function($view, $di) {
            $volt = new Volt($view, $di);
            $compiler = $volt->getCompiler();
            $compiler->addFilter('currency',your code);
        }
    ]);
    return $view;
});
```